# How to temporarily disable a service running as Local System?

Tags: windows, services

I am using Windows 7 and want to temporarily shutdown a service running as Local System. I am looking for a way to do it without having to reboot into Safe Mode but had no luck (even searching Google) so far.

I assume this can be done, because an Administrator account was used to create that service, and therefore should be able to disable it. I hope someone who is more familiar with Windows access control system will have the answer.

Comment: You'll want to post which services you are looking to disable.  Even more complex than the security settings are the dependencies. . .

Comment: Expanding on what surfasb has pointed out - you can of course control services from the command line.. And thus you can script control of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hit your windows key and then type `services.msc`, pause for a moment for the search to catch up and press enter.  This will (eventually: it can be slow) open a window that will let you browse services.  Find the one you want, right click on it, and if it's running you should see an option to stop it.